# At Command Is Not Actually Running

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian, osx

The code I used to set up the at command can be found here

```
at -f noti.sh -t ${sleepTimes[$i]}
```

The times work correctly as I can see the jobs listed successfully with `atq`.

The file noti.sh is in the same directory where the at command is being used and it contains:

```
if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "linux-gnu" ]]; then
    notify-send "Insomnia" "Time to take a rest"  -u critical -t 7000 -i sleep.ico
elif [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
    terminal-notifier -title "Insomnia" -message "Time to take a rest"  -sound "default"  -group rest -timeout 7 -appIcon sleep.png
fi
```

Both terminal-notifier and notify-send are installed on both respective platforms I've been testing this on. Why will the function not execute the way it should (show a notification bubble)?

Comment: I tried providing the full path and i also tried utilizing `/.noti.sh`

Comment: Are these GUI applications (`notify-send` and `terminal-notifier`)?  If so, you may need to set some environment variables (`DISPLAY=:0.0`, `XAUTHORITY=/home/your-username/.Xauthority` (or wherever it is), etc.)

Comment: I guess they are as it does show a notification bubble that isn't a native one so its invoking its own gui for the bubble. How do i set up those enviornment variables

Comment: I did copied the output of the command at the top of my script calling the at command and that didnt work should i have put it it at the top of the noti.sh? The output was `DISPLAY=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.5jte4rZAmH/org.macosforge.xquartz:0` im assuming by placing that at the top of the code it set a variable inside of my script called display

Comment: putting that at the top of the noti.sh did not work

Comment: How do i go about exporting a variable, sorry this is the first bash script ive ever written

Comment: I tried that and it still didn't work. I threw an echo at the top of the noti.sh to test if it was running but the echo never showed up is there something wrong about how im specifying the file? `at -f ~/git/Insomnia-Lite/noti.sh -t ${sleepTimes[$i]}`

Comment: i already ran a `chmod a+x` on the noti.sh so you dont need to write `./noti.sh` for it to execute

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58368/discussion-between-a-epstein-and-fox).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might be this (from `man at`):

> DESCRIPTION
>
> `at`  and  `batch` read commands from standard input or a specified file which are to be executed at a later time, **using `/bin/sh`**.

Also, if you run for example `at -f noti.sh -t 2...` it should output a warning like this:

```
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 4 at Mon May  8 13:51:00 2017
```

`/bin/sh` on Debian is a symlink to `/bin/dash`.
I guess you tested your script with `bash`, which has some [features not defined by POSIX](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism), i.e. they won't work in `dash` or, in general, with `/bin/sh`.

In your specific case, the problems are `[[ ]]` and `OSTYPE`, which are not supported by `dash`. Try to run

```
$ sh noti.sh
```

It will return the following error

```
noti.sh: 2: noti.sh: [[: not found
noti.sh: 4: noti.sh: [[: not found
```

whereas, running the script with `bash` does what you want.

To run the script as you intended, you might need to rewrite it to be compatible with `/bin/sh` (`dash` in your case), see [www.shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) for some help with this.